# HIVE datetime format with timezone

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have a unix timestamp that is getting converted using a view in HIVE before it gets inserted into a sql server database.  The problem I am having is I need the right format to insert it into a datetimeoffset(2) field in sql server.  Here is an example from hive:

> Query:
> select from_unixtime(1413587962, 'yyyy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss z');
>
> Result: 2014.10.17 11:19:22 UTC

SQL server is not able to convert that format implicitly.  If I run this is SQL server:

> Query: SELECT CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET(2), '2014.10.17 11:19:22 UTC')
>
> Result: Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

If I change the UTC to +00:00 SQL server converts to DATETIMEOFFSET(2) just fine.

What is the format that I need to use in HIVE to render the hours and min in the offset instead of the text time zone?  I have tired [+|-]hh:mm, hh:mm, and z.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be does this help, Captial Z 
    select from_unixtime(1413587962, 'yyyy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss Z') 
    2014.10.17 11:19:22 +0000

```
 If that does not work direct +00:00 works? 
select from_unixtime(1413587962, 'yyyy.MM.dd hh:mm:ss +00:00')
```

Comment: That gets me closer, SQL server is still not able to implicitly convert +0000.  It needs to have +00:00.  Thank you.

Comment: Just saw your edit.  That is what I ended up doing.  Thanks!